# Provider null after pop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to use Provider with MVVM architecture, I have a very strange error with provider, on the main page there are 3 sections, banner, discounts and categories, when I change the quantity of goods in discounts, everything works, but after switching to a category and back, it already gives an error when I change the quantity of goods,
the data is not null, I think the problem is with the provider, the scheme is as follows:

`discount section-> quantity of goods -> works`

`home-> category-> go back-> quantity of goods in discounts-> not working`

***Demo [project](https://github.com/aleks990822/provider_test)***

```
The following _CastError was thrown building MainPage(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<AllGoodsViewModel?>, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#a9792], MediaQuery, _InheritedProviderScope<MainPageListViewModel?>], state: _MainPageState#eb568):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MainPage MainPage:file:///Users/.../lib/main.dart:93:21
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Element.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3229:31)
#1      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:245:17)
#2      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:261:4)
#3      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:908:12)
#4      ScreenUtil.screenWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/src/screen_util.dart:148:37)
#5      ScreenUtil.scaleWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/src/screen_util.dart:167:28)
#6      ScreenUtil.setWidth (package:flutter_screenutil/src/screen_util.dart:182:41)
#7      SizeExtension.w (package:flutter_screenutil/src/size_extension.dart:9:32)
#8      _MainPageState.build (package:.../View/MainPage.dart:240:78)
#9      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:27)
#10     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4806:15)
#11     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4977:11)
#12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4529:5)
#13     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#14     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:891:21)
#15     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#16     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#17     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#18     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#22     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#23     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#24     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

ScreenUtilInitService

```
class ScreenUtilInitService z{
  /// A helper widget that initializes [ScreenUtil]
  ScreenUtilInitService({required this.builder, Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget Function(BuildContext) builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: Size(375, 812),
        builder: (context, widget) => builder(context)
    );
  }
}
```

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();

}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;
  Widget _present = SplashScreen();

  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
      }
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      await message();
      await rootWidget();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      setState(() {
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> rootWidget() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final id = prefs.get("idAddress");
    final logged = prefs.getBool("logged") ?? false;
    if ((FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid != null && logged) || id != null) {
      setState(() {
        _present =  MainPage();
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _present = OfferPage();
      });
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeDB();
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
    listeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_error) {
      return MaterialApp(home:SplashScreen());
    }
    if (!_initialized) {
      return MaterialApp(home:SplashScreen());
    }
    return RootPage().mainPage(present: _present);
  }
}
```

and RootPage

```
class RootPage {
  

  Widget mainPage({Widget? present}){
    return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/ProfilePage': (context) => ProfilePage(),
          '/MainPage': (context) => MainPage(),
          '/CartPage': (context) => CartPage(),
        },
        builder: (context, widget) {
          return ScreenUtilInitService(
              builder: (context) => widget!
          );
        },
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => MainPageListViewModel(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (context) => CartViewModel(),
                child: CartPage()
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => AllGoodsViewModel(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => GoodsViewModel(),
            ),
          ],
          child: present != null ? present : MainPage(),
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

MainPage

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    setting();
    super.initState();
    _scrollListener();
    _notification();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.removeListener(() { });
    _scrollController.dispose();
    NotificationCenter().unsubscribe('cart');
    NotificationCenter().unsubscribe('address');
    super.dispose();
  }

  void setting() async {
    final cart = await SQFliteService.cart.getCount();
    final address = await SQFliteService.location.current();
    setState((){
      _address = address;
      showCart = cart == 0 ? false : true;
    });
    Provider.of<MainPageListViewModel>(context, listen: false).deliveryRequest() ;
    Provider.of<MainPageListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchBanner();
    Provider.of<MainPageListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchCategory();
    Provider.of<AllGoodsViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchSale();
    Provider.of<MainPageListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchLaunchMessage(context);

  }

  void _scrollListener(){
    _scrollController.addListener(() {

    ///setState is null after pop after category
    //   setState(() {
    //  _bottomOffSet = _scrollController.offset;
    //   });
    });
  }

  void _notification(){

    NotificationCenter().subscribe('cart', () async {
      final result = await SQFliteService.cart.getCount();
      setState(() {
        showCart = result == 0 ? false : true;
        print("update");
      });
    });

    NotificationCenter().subscribe('address', () async {
      final result = await SQFliteService.location.current();
      setState((){
        _address = result;
      });
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final models = Provider.of<MainPageListViewModel>(context);
    final sale = Provider.of<AllGoodsViewModel>(context);

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Container(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            ...
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) => Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Column(
                  children: [
                    bannerW(),
                    ViewSale(model: sale.goods),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),
                    ViewCategory(model: models.category)
                  ]
              ),
            ),
                childCount: 1
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

ViewSale

```
class _ViewSaleState extends State<ViewSale> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 15),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Скидки", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter", fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 18))),
          ),
          Container(
            height: ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2.4) - 21) + 71,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: widget.model.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (item, index) {
                  return ChangeNotifierProvider(
                     create: (context) => AllGoodsViewModel(),
                    child: ViewGoodsSale(model: widget.model[index])
                   );
                }),
          )
        ]
    );
  }
}
```

ViewSaleGoods

```
class _ViewGoodsSaleState extends State<ViewGoodsSale> {

  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      Provider.of<AllGoodsViewModel>(context, listen: false).setting(widget.model);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final model = Provider.of<AllGoodsViewModel>(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    Widget inCart(){
    return Container(
      key: _key,
      height: 31,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanDown: (details) {
          Goods? item = widget.model;
          RenderBox _cardBox = _key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          final localPosition = details.localPosition;
          final localDx = localPosition.dx;
          if (localDx <= _cardBox.size.width/2) {
            Goods value = cart.firstWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);
            if (item.optState == 0 ? value.orderCount <= 1 : value.orderCount <= value.opt!.count) {
              setState(() {
                context.read<AllGoodsViewModel>().setCountInCart(0);
                final ind = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);
                if (ind != -1) {
                  cart[ind].orderCount = 0;
                  SQFliteService.cart.delete(cart[ind].id);
                  cart.removeAt(ind);
                }
              });
            } else {
              model.haveItem(item: item, operation: item.optState == 0 ? -1 : (-1 * value.opt!.count));
            }
          } else {
            model.haveItem(item: item, operation: item.optState == 0 ? 1 : item.count);
          }
        },
        child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Design.appColor),
              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10)),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ))
          ),
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Container(
            child: RichText(
              text:  TextSpan(
                text: "",
                children:[
                  WidgetSpan(
                    alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                    child: Icon(Icons.remove, size: 14, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "  ${widget.model.optState == 0 ? (widget.model.minPrice ?? widget.model.price) : widget.model.opt!.price} ₽  ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontFamily: "Inter"
                    ),
                  ),
                  WidgetSpan(
                    alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                    child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 14, color: Colors.white),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),// Your TextButton code goes here.
    );
  }

  Widget noInCart(){
    return Container(
      key: _key,
      height: 31,
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(model.orderBg),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10)),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ))
        ),
        onPressed: (){
          Goods? item = widget.model;
          model.haveItem(item: item, operation: item.optState == 0 ? 1 : item.count);
        },
        child: Container(
          child: RichText(
            text:  TextSpan(
              text: "${widget.model.optState == 0 ? widget.model.minPrice == null ? widget.model.price : widget.model.minPrice : widget.model.opt!.price} ₽ ",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: widget.model.minPrice != null ? Design.grey : Colors.black,
                  decoration: widget.model.optState == 0 && widget.model.minPrice != null ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontFamily: "Inter"

              ),
              children:[
                TextSpan(
                  text: widget.model.minPrice == null ? "" : " ${widget.model.price} ₽",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: "Inter"
                  ),
                ),

                WidgetSpan(
                  alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 14, color: Colors.black),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget card({required Size size}) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: (size.width/2.4) - 11,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: (size.width/2.4) - 21,
                  padding:  EdgeInsets.all(1),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        image: NetworkImage(widget.model.images.first)
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Design.lightGrey
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: context.read<AllGoodsViewModel>().countInCart == 0 ? false : true,
                  child: Container(
                    height: (size.width/2.4) - 21,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    ),
                    child: Visibility(
                      visible: true,
                      child: Center(
                        child: model.orderCountText,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ]
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              height: 29,
              child: Text(widget.model.name,
                maxLines: 2,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  fontFamily: "Inter",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 6),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: (context.read<AllGoodsViewModel>().countInCart == 0) ? noInCart() : inCart()
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  return card(size: size);
  }

}
```

ViewCategory

```
class _ViewCategoryState extends State<ViewCategory> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 1),
        itemCount: widget.model.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Design.lightGrey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                    ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: (index.isOdd ? 0 : 5) , left: (index.isOdd ? 5 : 0), bottom: 10 ),
                      child: Image.network(widget.model[index].category?.url ?? "")
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                      left: 10,
                      right: 10,
                      top: 8,
                      child: Text(widget.model[index].category?.name ?? "", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter", fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 12.sp)),
                  )
                ]
              ),
              onTap: () async {
                if (widget.model[index].category != null) {
                  final data = widget.model[index].category!;
                  final category = CategoryData(id: data.id, name: data.name);
                  if (data.tags == null) {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AllGoodsViewModel(),
                              child: AllCategoryGoodsPage(category: category))
                        )
                    );
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: GoodsViewModel(),
                                child: GoodsPage(category: category))
                        )
                    );
                  }
                  FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: "Category", parameters: null);
                }
              }
            );
          },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be best to write null-safe code to avoid this sort of error. It is difficult to tell which bang (!) value is causing it from what was provided.

Comment: maybe you remove your controller after get back, try check it after get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the error was not at all in the provider, but in ScreenUtilInitService I changed it to

```
class ScreenUtilInitService {
  Widget build(Function(BuildContext) builder) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: Size(375, 812),
        builder: (context, widget) => builder(context)
    );
  }
}
```

and removed `ScreenUtilInitService` from `GoodsPage` and `AllCategoryGoodsPage`  so `ScreenUtilInitService` is not redefined as a widget, which resulted in the error

Answer (score 2):

> "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him for a lifetime."

Thus, I try to explain what to do generally.

Firstly, look at the *error stacktrace*. You only provide the error *message* without *stacktrace* - thus no wonder nobody can see which line of code throws the error.

P.S. If you cannot find the stack trace, search or create a separate question (in some strange cases stack trace is not easy to find).

When you get the stack trace, you can read which line of code has this null pointer error, and which lines are calling that function. Suppose it is `a.dart` line `123` throwing the error, then look at that line and examine why that happens.

You may want to do "logging" or "debugging" to dig out further clues.

Then the bug should be found and solved easily. If not, try to create a *minimal* reproducible sample - your current sample is still very big and it is hard for people to dig and find bug for you :)

Comment: I found the point of the error, but I don’t understand why, I added the place of the error

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE will usually have great stack trace debugging. If you are using vscode, you can turn on the following two options for your error tracking.

[image]

If you're using Android Studio. Run -> View Breakpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"**Null check operator used on a null value**" is a error you get when you use a bang operator (!) on a nullable instance which wasn't initialized.

In your "ViewSaleGoods" file you have it at -

```
    if (item.optState == 0 ? value.orderCount <= 1 : value.orderCount <= value.opt!.count) { // Here .....
                  setState(() {
                    context.read<AllGoodsViewModel>().setCountInCart(0);
                    final ind = cart.indexWhere((element) => element.id == item.id);
                    if (ind != -1) {
                      cart[ind].orderCount = 0;
                      SQFliteService.cart.delete(cart[ind].id);
                      cart.removeAt(ind);
                    }
                  });
                } else {
              model.haveItem(item: item, operation: item.optState == 0 ? -1 : (-1 * value.opt!.count)); // here...
            }
    
                TextSpan(
                        text: "  ${widget.model.optState == 0 ? (widget.model.minPrice ?? widget.model.price) : widget.model.opt!.price} ₽  ", // and here ....
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            fontFamily: "Inter"
                        ),
                      ),
```

so anyone of those is turning out null so the error. Now to fix it you can use some ways like -

```
    // Use variable and if check
    var nullSafe;
    if (value.opt != null) {
        nullSafe = value.opt; // now you can use these variable instead
    }

    // Or use ?. and ??
    value.opt?count ?? "some default value"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This has formatting problems.  You have your own... utternaces? mixed in with the code.

Comment: Tabs does not work here  and I copied a formatted code but after pasting it just got that way. I edited and added some spaces but can't format it like vscode for sure.